# calling a file inside another file in php

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to include or execute code from a separate file?

For example, if we have 2 files:

**a.php** which contains:

```
<?php echo "i'm a.php"; ?>
```

and **b.php** which contains:

```
<?php 
echo "i'm b.php";
// some code here to "execute" a.php so that it prints i'm a.php as the output.
?>
```

When b.php is run it should display:

```
i'm b.php
i'm a.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <?php 
 echo "i'm b.php";
 include('a.php');
 ?>
```

C.

Comment: if the a.php file has reference to other files inside it, will it execute correctly? 
thanks for ur reply

Comment: What if file a and b are having same variable names?

Comment: Its all in the manual: include files are included in global scope and default namespace. Superglobals are in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

just universal solution (but maybe denied by local PHP-server configuration):

```
echo file('http://your-remote-host/path/a.php');
```

or your a.php must provide some gate:

```
<? # a.php
function a_php_output()
{
return "i'm a.php";
}
?>

<? # b.php
echo "i'm b.php";
include('a.php');
echo a_php_output();
?>
```